# Is anyone in central Mexico interested in a get-together?

Tags: discusión, get-together

I'll be in Mexico City, Guadalajara, and León, GTO during this month (March 2014).

If anyone is in the area and interested in grabbing a coffee or beer, let me know! :)

---

Estaré en Ciudad de México, Guadalajara, y León GTO este mes (Marzo 2014).

Si le interesa a alguien reunirnos para un café o cerveza, avísame :)

Comment: Yo estaré por Cuba para esa fecha, lo mismo si hay alguien por allá. Lo que no voy a tener internet :)

Comment: Gracias... estoy pensando en ir a Habana también... pero es un poco complicado para mi porque soy estadounidense... jiji

Comment: I'd if you come to Monterrey.

Comment: @AlfredoOsorio: I was there just 3 weeks ago!  ¡Lástima!